# Could not load type Master Page Error

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, localhost, windows-server

When i run my application on windows server i get below error.This application run smoothly on localhost.What is cause of the problem.

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'KorkmazPortal.SiteMaster'.
Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="KorkmazPortal.SiteMaster" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <%@ Register Src="UserControl/Exchange.ascx" TagName="Exchange" TagPrefix="uc" %>

Source File: /portal/Site.Master    Line: 1
```

Comment: Have you set up the site folder in IIS to be an application?

Comment: @adback03, are you talking about virtual directory or?

Answer (score 1):

Know this is an old post, but I recently hit this issue.  My web setup project wasn't including the web project's library in the installed output.  Once i manually copied the .dll over to the remote server, everything worked fine.

In my case the clue was that my web project worked fine locally in debug mode. Just wouldn't work when deploying remotely.

Hope this helps someone someday.

Answer (score 0):

Be Sure Your "bin" folder path is "/portal/bin"
means bin folder is placed in portal folder...bin folder and your master page in same directory..